# How to make custom list style in word [that use number in words instead numerical]?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

i usually write documents in word that require to have a list style that user numbers in words instead of numerical; also in different LTR and RTL languages; i was wondering if there's a possibility to make a custom list like

Section One [not 1]

```
1.1
```

Section Two

```
2.1
```

Section Three

```
3.1
```

...etc

and if i can make it as well in different languages; i can write the whole numbers in words if needed.

Comment: Noone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way of accomplishing this.
Start by defining a new multilevel list (even if you only require first level). Make sure you have level one is selected in the dialog box. Then, delete everything inside text field "Enter formatting for number" and type **Section**. This is the static part of your list.

To add dynamically changing number, click on dropdown list "Number style for this level" and choose "One, Two, Three ...". Text One with gray background should appear right after "Section" inside "Enter formatting for number" text field. Gray background indicates text which updates dynamically (depending on number of headings of same level).

After you click OK, the list will appear in your document. The best part about this is that *Cardtext formatting (One, Two, Three ...) is language dependent. If you change language of the text and update it, it will update based on selected language!

Same applies if you use ordinal numbers (First, Second, Third ...) for your list.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by formatting the NUMBER for Heading 1 to be 1pt size, hidden (white text as well so not visible with paragraph marks on, and followed by nothing).  In the screenshot below, I have inserted the Number style "1,2,3..." but it is "invisible" in the "Enter formatting for number" textbox above because I have formatted the Font (button alongside) for the number to be 1pt, white and hidden text.

Leave the font size for the Heading 1 style itself (ie its TEXT) as is (eg 11 pt).

Then after you apply the Heading 1 style to your paragraph, type "Heading" or "Section" but use a STYLEREF field for Heading 1 style (which will find the current "hidden" number for your paragraph) and add a CARDTEXT switch (to change it from 1 to one).

Note also the text indent is set to 0 and follow with nothing.

Using a STYLEREF field also means that if you add/move main headings, if you select your entire document and press F9, the "text" numbers will update to their new value.

To avoid having to insert the STYLEREF field each time, you might find it easier to copy your first heading once it's set up with the field, and then just paste it for each new main heading.

[image]

and the field code (SHIFT F9 to toggle between code and result)
[image]